How to create a Fortran Interface for a C function that takes a Fortran function as input using Fortran-C Interoperability?
I have a C library with a function Calculate_Integral that performs definite integration on a given C float function within specified limits and parameters. The signature of this C function looks something like this:
float Calculate_Integral(float (*func)(float), float a, float b, int n);

Here, func is a pointer to a C function, a and b are the integration limits, and n is the number of intervals.
I need to call this Calculate_Integral function from Fortran, passing a Fortran real function to it. The C function should be able to evaluate the Fortran function at various points and calculate the integral.
How can I write a Fortran interface for Fortran-C Interoperability for the Calculate_Integral C function so that it can accept a Fortran function as input, perform the integration in C, and return the result to Fortran?
Additionally, how should the Fortran interface and the corresponding C code be structured to handle this interoperability correctly?
Here is a simplified version of what I'm aiming for,
Fortran Code:
interface
    function FCalculate_Integral(func, a, b, n) bind(C, name="Calculate_Integral")
        import :: C_FLOAT, C_INT
        implicit none
        real(C_FLOAT) :: Calculate_Integral
        real(C_FLOAT), value :: a, b
        integer(C_INT), value :: n
        interface
            function func(x) bind(C)
                import :: C_FLOAT
                real(C_FLOAT) :: func
                real(C_FLOAT), value :: x
            end function func
        end interface
    end function FCalculate_Integral
end interface

C Code:
float Calculate_Integral(float (*func)(float), float a, float b, int n) {
    // Implementation of the integral calculation
}

How should the function pointers and types be managed to ensure proper interoperability? Any example codes or detailed explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Is there anything wrong with your current code?

Have you investigated c_funptr and c_funloc? Is https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/C_005fFUNLOC.html of any help?
